# Should r0-r12 be saved always in case of IRQ or lesser regs be saved

Tags: linux, arm

A trivial question. In case of an IRQ should the irq_handler save r0-r12 on stack always or there can be exception to that.

AFAIK r0-r12 shd be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can confirm from the table below except in `FIQ` mode, registers `r0-r12` are shared thus newly entered mode is responsible for not destroying previous mode's registers.

[Organization of general-purpose registers and Program Status Registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/CEGIBCCG.html)

[image: Organization of general-purpose registers and Program Status Registers]

Comment: Then why all documentation in ARM says about saving LR and SPSR and not r0-r12. SRS instruction is just for LR and SPSR.

Comment: @mSO It is crucial to save LR and SPSR if you want to have reentrant interrupt handling. Saving other registers depends on how many you destroy within your irq routine.